# Supervisorctl Fails to load my new project

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, flask, supervisord

I have one existing `flask` project under `supervisorctl` that works flawlessly!

I added a new flask app called `Blog` but this fails to load under supervisorctl.

If I start it manually, it works, by doing:

```
mongod --dbpath /home/www/blog/mongodb

gunicorn myblog:app -b mysite.com:8080
```

**However, if run the project on `supervisorctl` via:**

```
supervisorctl start blog
```

**it does this:**

```
blog: ERROR (abnormal termination)
```

**If I check the `stderr` logs, I get:**

```
  File "/home/www/blog/myblog.py", line 5, in <module>
    from flaskext.markdown import Markdown
ImportError: No module named flaskext.markdown
```

**Supervisor config (.conf):**

```
[program:blog]
command = gunicorn myblog:app -b mysite.com:8080 --loglevel=critical
directory = /home/www/blog
user = myuser
```

This seems like a simple error - oops I must not have installed `flaskext.markdown` right?? Wrong! if I go to my directory with this `flask app`, and enable `virtualenv` its already installed...

**Thus, I am not sure what to do from here? Does anyone have any thoughts? Thank you.**

Comment: Can you add information about your supervisor settings?

Comment: Including the .conf file under /etc/supervisor/config.d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add virtualenv path to the command line:

```
[program:blog]
command = /path/to/virtualenv/bin/gunicorn myblog:app -b mysite.com:8080 --loglevel=critical
directory = /home/www/blog
user = myuser
```

Save changes, then reload supervisor config and try to start blog again.

Comment: I tried this, and it told me the command was in the wrong order. I think [OPTIONS] [APP], specifically: gunicorn: error: unrecognized arguments: --loglevel=critical

Comment: Got it, it was a minor fix --log-level instead of --loglevel :) Thanks!